# How to delete data from database using 2 different IDs with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

In the database, I have an 'id' and 'reply_id' column along with other columns.
I'm trying to delete data using the main 'id', at the same time, I need to check if other rows match the same 'id' with 'reply_id'. If a match is found, then all rows with 'reply_id' matching the 'id', should be deleted.

For example: there are 10 rows with the 'id' of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, and the 'reply_id' with 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10. If I try to delete the 'id' with the number 8, then all the rows with 'reply_id' number 8, should also be deleted.

I'm learning PHP so I'm no expert. The code below only deletes the row with the 'id' and not the other rows with 'reply_id' that match the same number.

```
        if(isset($_POST['yesdelete'])){

            $delete_id  =  $_POST['deleteid'];

            $db->query('DELETE FROM msgs WHERE id = :id');
            $db->bind(':id', $delete_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

            $run = $db->execute();

            if($run){

                redirect('my-messages.php');

            }

        }
```

Comment: What are you trying to `bind()`, as @RiggsFolly is saying that does not exist by default and most importantly.. `query()` executes directly unlike `prepare()` so there is nothing to 'bind' to.

Comment: @Xorifelse Good point I missed that completely

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['yesdelete'])){

            $delete_id  =  $_POST['deleteid'];

            $db->prepare('DELETE FROM msgs WHERE id = :id or reply_id = :id');
            $db->bind(':id', $delete_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

            $run = $db->execute();

            if($run){

                redirect('my-messages.php');

            }

        }
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check, the main problem is need the condition for reply_id

Comment: See [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42639010/how-to-delete-data-from-database-using-2-different-ids-with-pdo#comment72405622_42639010) and [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42639010/how-to-delete-data-from-database-using-2-different-ids-with-pdo#comment72405643_42639010)

Comment: Now you have the issue of using `:id` twice. That also will not work

Comment: Actually, that would work if emulated prepared statements are on. Which is btw, not shown in the code at all. Again. Too many unanswered questions, that you are trying to answer with a questionable answer. A bit early.

Comment: Thanks @ĐàoMinhHạt! You focused on my question and understood the problem I had. Thanks again!

Comment: Just so we're clear, emulated prepares should be turned off in the DB-class to begin with. But yes, the code will work (apart from the non-existent `->bind()`-parameter).

Comment: I'm actually using query instead of prepare and the DB class is in another file. Everything is now running smoothly. Thank you guys for your help!